# Raspberry 3.3 V to 5 V level conversion at 5MHz

Tags: raspberry-pi, frequency, dc-dc-converter, cmos, high-frequency

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 to handle my cards.

I need to convert 3.3 V GPIO of Raspberry to 5 V for my cards.
Actually I use CD4050 (Non-Inverting Buffer) to convert 3.3 V to 5 V.

I have mesaured output GPIO 3.3 V of Raspberry at 5MHz, the signals is correct.
[image: GPIO RASPBERRY]

I have mesured output of CD4050 with 5MHz, the signals is very bad.
[image: GPIO RASPBERRY]

I use WiringPi with Qt for control GPIO

I think the CD4050 is not able to work at 5MHz (Work in Detect logic level)

I'm new in electronic systems, i would like your idea.

Comment: Please provide a schematic.

Comment: "New to electronics" and CD4k don't mix that well. Consider using a 74HCT part instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't recommend just using any 74HCT logic gate, either. See my answer below.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I could understand "new to electronic", but I'm not really understand the means of "I'm new to engineering" that often we read here. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the CD4050 [datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/CD/CD4049UBC.pdf).

It says there that the output transition time from high to low and from low to high with a 5V supply voltage (you didn't specify, but I'll go ahead and assume that) is typically 60ns each (max 110/120ns). That means that for a full period of a signal, a total delay of typically 120ns, and up to 230ns will accumulate.

Now, a period of a 5 MHz signal is \$\frac1{5\text{ MHz}}=\frac1{5\text{ M}\frac1{\text s}}=\frac15\text{ µs}=200\text{ ns}\$. So, if we can assume *typical* transition duration, you're barely ok, but you'd normally design for worst-case, so this wouldn't work. You chose a insufficiently fast device.

Another note: **read** datasheets. The high-level input threshold voltage of the CD4050 is 2.75V, whereas the transition from logical low to logical high on the Raspberry pi would happen somewhere around \$\frac{3.3\text{ V}}2=1.65\text{ V}\$. So with just a little voltage lost between the Pi's output and your CD4050's input, the CD4050 wouldn't even "see" a high on the input. Uh-oh. I can't really read your miniature signal plots, but this might already be the case here. Also, it means that your timing constraints get even worse – notice how the slope of the rising edge of your input signal isn't overly steep? The point where that voltage crosses 2.75V is the *earliest* point at which you can start to count the low-to-high output transition delay explained above – if at (that point + delay) your falling edge already occurs, your output will never see "high". Again, wrong choice of device to do 3.3V to 5V conversion.

There's a lot of dedicated so-called *level translator* devices out there, I don't understand why people insist on using logic gates for this. Of course it works, but most of the time, that's by luck, because the input signal reaches sufficiently above the half the output voltage swing. Also, time-proven technology in honours and all, but the CD4050 was designed in the early 70s, I think – I don't know where you've got the recommendation to use that from, but taking advice on digital signal handling from things based in the 70s might not be the best approach. There simply has been way too much movement in semiconductor technology.

Looking at your signal, I'd also assume there's more than sensible signal degradation due to badly layouted PCB traces or unsuitable wires – 5 MHz is *not **that** much*, but it's still the beginning of where you need to consider high-frequency design rules. You can't just use a piece of flying wire to connect devices talking at 5 MHz and hope it'll work reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The CH1 wire for mesure is degraded because of quality of my cable.
What is the way or what component you will use ?

Comment: ti.com -> Products -> interface -> Voltage level translation -> Unidirectional

Comment: I'd probably go a bit in the direction of the "neo-7400" SN74LV4T125 or so. Dunno, depends on your application, actually.

Comment: @JimmyB indeed!